# Why do ceiling fan speeds decrease when I pull the chain?

Tags: usability, design

A typical 3-speed ceiling fan goes HIGH-MED-LOW-OFF when you pull the chain. Why not the opposite order?

Comment: Likely because a succesful 3-speed fan manufacturer back in the day did it that way and everyone else copied (and/or used the exact same switch hardware).

Answer (score 2):

## The cooling effect

Because the main purpose of a cooling fan is to cool you, and the **cooling effect** is directly proportional to **airflow**, where the higher the airflow the higher the cooling effect.

Low speed is recommended when the environment is cooler, like at night (when you need the device 'less').

## The mathematical sense

In a mathematical sense, the hotter it is, the more likely you are to switch on the device, thus it makes sense to start with a higher airflow.

## The psychology

In a psychological sense, you are likely to turn the device whilst already feeling discomfort, and we normally prefer discomforts to go away quickly rather than gradually. Hence the initial high settings.

The same principle can apply to umbrellas - if you have the need to open one, you would normally prefer a big one rather than a small one (folded form factor obviously plays a part, but consider two umbrellas with the same folded form factor and weight).

And (interestingly) with pain killers. If you have a pounding headache, would you really not opt for the express version:

[image: The Nuropen range, showing both normal and express versions]

Comment: This all seems to assume 'maximum' is the default preference from off. I don't know if that can be validated easily--for example, auto AC units don't start at 'high' by default. (Also note that ceiling fans are used in heating seasons as well to circulate air, often on the lowest setting).

Comment: @DA01 - not the default, but most likely.